# optional attributes in custom tags, prevent name conflict with model attributes

Tags: jsp

In a custom tag I have a optional attribute like this

```
<%@ attribute name="message" required="false" type="java.lang.String" %>
```

and do something when the attribute is set

```
<c:if test="${not empty message}">do something</c:if>
```

but when there is a variable "message" with scope session or request it gets mixed.

Is there any possibility to decide if a variable comes from the model or is an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much easier way. Attributes have their own page scope. When accessing them simply name the scope:

${pageScope.message}

Answer (score 0):

One ugly way is to take the attribute with scope page and put it into another variable:

```
<% 
int scope = PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE;
Object msg = jspContext.getAttribute("message", scope);
jspContext.setAttribute("messageattribute", msg);
%>
```